# Leaking window-wiper fluid from head-light nozzles. Is a broken pump likely?

Tags: windshield-wipers, pump, alfa-romeo

My Alfa Romea Guilia (2017 model) since a few weeks looses windshield-wiper fluid at an alarming rate.
Fill the reservoir to capacity (about 4 liters) and about a week later the "reservoir nearly empty" light comes on. With hardly any use of the sprayers at all. (I used to be able to go for several months without a top-up.)

The reservoir feeds both the nozzles on the windshield and on the head-lights.
I have noticed 2 puddles of fluid on the garage-floor roughly were the head-lights are located when the car is inside.
As long as there is fluid in the reservoir the nozzles still seem to spray normally.

The car was in a (non-brand) workshop for an oil-change a few days ago. While up on the lift I asked the mechanic (a friend of mine) to take a look at it. He presumes that the pump has a broken seal and some fluid is leaking through continuously, leaking out at the lowest point which are the head-light nozzles.

If I'm sure it is the pump I can order a replacement myself (I can get an employee-discount as I happen to work for the manufacturer of that pump) and have it fitted by this mechanic friend of mine.
If other problems are likely I will have to make an appointment at an Alfa (or other Stellantis-group) dealer-workshop, which will be expensive and the only one near me  currently has a 6 weeks waiting time for non-emergency repairs.

The pump does seem a reasonable explanation.
Does it make sense, or could there be something else going on that I'm missing?